# oracle form bad bind variable

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I am using post-query to display my `email_address`.

Tables

**Portfolio**

```
Portfolio_Number    PK  Number (7,0)    Not Null
Investor_Number     FK  Number (7,0)    Not Null
Portfolio_Description   Varchar2 (50)   Null
```

**Investor**

```
Investor_Number PK  Number (7,0)    Not Null
First_Name          Varchar2 (25)   Not Null
Last_Name           Varchar2 (30)   Not Null
Email_Address       Varchar2 (50)   Not Null
```

**datablock: PORTFOLIO**

```
display item: EMAIL_ADDRESS
```

**post_query:**

```
select Email_address
into :PORTFOLIO.EMAIL_ADDRESS
FROM Inverstor
where Inverstor_number =:PORTFOLIO.Inverstor_number;
```

Line 4 error bad bind variable PORTFOLIO.Inverstor_number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare:

```
      Investor_Number     FK  Number (7,0)    Not Null
      --------
```

vs.

```
where Inverstor_number =:PORTFOLIO.Inverstor_number;
      ----R----                    ----R----
```

Fix spelling; it is `investor`, not `inveRstor`.